# Runtime Exception as invalid operation Exception Occured

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I got error while debugging application invalid operation Exception Occurred

```
namespace CompanyServiceHost 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CompanyService.CompanyService)))
            {
                host.Open();// error occurred in this line 
                Console.WriteLine("host started @" + DateTime.Now);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I need to try create a web service to consume it, and I am hosting in console application

Comment: What does the exception message look like exactly?

Comment: Can you post the code for `CompanyService.CompanyService`?  Chances are the host isn't being created properly and it's state is not `Created`, which is why you're getting an InvalidOperationException.